# Linear Maps and component functions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove or disprove the following.

Let $f$: $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}^2$.

be a map with component functions $g$ and $h$ such that $f(x,y)$ = $(g(x,y),h(x,y))$. If $f$ is linear, then $g$ and $h$ are linear as well.

What's the best method to prove/disprove the following? Would showing f be linear in terms of g and h work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $f(k_1(x_1,y_1)+k_2(x_2,y_2))=k_1f(x_1,y_1)+k_2f(x_2,y_2)$, i.e.$$\begin{bmatrix}g(k_1(x_1,y_1)+k_2(x_2,y_2))\\h(k_1(x_1,y_1)+k_2(x_2,y_2))\end{bmatrix}=k_1\begin{bmatrix}g(x_1,y_1)\\h(x_1,y_1)\end{bmatrix}+k_2\begin{bmatrix}g(x_2,y_2)\\h(x_2,y_2)\end{bmatrix}$$which gives $g(k_1(x_1,y_1)+k_2(x_2,y_2))=k_1g(x_1,y_1)+k_2g(x_2,y_2)$ and similarly for $h$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I suppose the statement is true then.

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, true indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{\pi_1,\pi_2\}$ the dual basis of  $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$.  Then  $g=\pi_1\circ f$ and $h=\pi_2\circ f$.Then use that the composition of linear maps is linear as well.

Comment: If $f = \operatorname{id}$, then of course $g = \pi_1$ and $h = \pi_2$ are the dual basis vectors to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, otherwise this is false.

Comment: Edited, thanks.